# Can a smart pointer be optimized away?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Mind the code

```
...
{
    int* p = new int(0);
    std::unique_ptr<int> q(p);
    ...
    // make use of 'p'
}
...
```

In the code above, the unique pointer *q* is used solely to free *p*, when time comes. *Q* is not used by itself.
Since *q* is never used below the line where it is declared, it can seemingly be released immediately after being declared, thus making use of *p* "use after free".
The question is *q* **guaranteed** to live on until going out of the current scope, or the compiler's optimizer is free to free it before ?

Comment: The compiler can do any optimization as long as the observable behavior isn't changed - that's the as-if rule.  `new` and `delete` operators aren't observable behavior since C++14, IIRC.

Comment: Assuming optimizations are turned on, the compiler probably will do an SSA optimization.  It could evaporate q entirely, and inline the destructor in the assembly equivalent of a "finally" block after the last use of q or p.  To know for sure, you'll need to look at the optimized assembly of your code with your compiler on your platform.

Comment: It makes a huge difference if the compiler destructs p after last mention of q or last mention of p :)  Of course I could look into the assembly code, but I'm looking for stable behavior over different (including newer) compiler versions.

Comment: @L.F.: in fact, [it is the new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation) which can be elided and so can change observable behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the as-if rule, compiler is allowed to do any optimization as long as observable behavior is identical.

Freeing immediately `q`/`p` would not be allowed, as then you will use dangling pointer.

Though it can call destructor before end of scope:

```
{
    int* p = new int(0);
    std::unique_ptr<int> q(p);
    ...
    // make use of 'p'
    ...
    // No longer use of p (and q)
    ...
    // Ok, can delete p/q now (as long there are no observable behaviors changes)
    ...
}
```

As `operator new`/`delete` might be changed globally, compiler would generally not have enough information (linker has though), so consider they have (potentially) observable behaviors (as any external functions).

c++14 allows some elisions/optimisation of new expression, so

```
{
    delete new int(42);
    int* p1 = new int(0);
    int* p2 = new int(0);
    std::unique_ptr<int> q2(p2);
    std::unique_ptr<int> q1(p1);
    ...
    // make use of 'p1'/p2
    ...
}
```

Can be "replaced" by

```
{
    // delete new int(42); // optimized out
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> qs{new int [] {0, 0}}; // only one allocation instead of 2
    int* p1 = q->get();
    int* p2 = q->get() + 1;
    ...
    // make use of 'p1'/p2
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've realized the answer to my own question:
In the code

```
{
    int* p = new int(0);
    std::unique_ptr<int> q(p);
    ...
    // HERE
}
```

the destructor of *q* **is** guaranteed to be called upon scope exit (*HERE*).
While the compiler is allowed to allocate and free registers for variables as it pleases, the destructor is guaranteed to be called in a particular place - scope exit.
How do I know ?
Because this is what enables C++ [scope guard](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard). Oftentimes the scope guard is used to release a mutex on scope exit - this is something that needs to be guaranteed.